# Где можно найти такой архитип для мавена?

Tags: maven, spring, spring-mvc, google-app-engine

Где можно найти такой архитип для мавена : google app engine + spring MVC?

И как его добавить в мавен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gwt-spring-archetype](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-spring-archetype/), например.

Скачиваете jar-ник, устанавливаете его в локальный репозиторий, пользуетесь.

Comment: а без gwt можно?

Comment: Попробуйте [GAE Guestbook Archetype](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.archetypes/guestbook-archetype/1.8.4)